# X-13ARIMA-SEATS Errors in R

Tags: r, seasonality

I'm trying to run a relatively simple seasonal adjustment using the seasonal package in R and I keep getting an error of

> Error: X-13 has run but produced no data

Because of how my data is processed, I'm using custom holidays and trading day adjustments, and I can use one or the other independently, but get this error when I run both at the same time.

```
 m <- seas(foodanddrink,
          xreg=cbind(Monday,Tuesday, Wednesday,Thursday,lom),
          regression.usertype=cbind('td','td','td','td','lom'))

m <- seas(foodanddrink,
          xreg=cbind(SatRollOver),
          regression.usertype=cbind('holiday'))

m <- seas(foodanddrink,
          xreg=cbind(Monday),
          regression.usertype=cbind('td'))
```

all work, whereas

```
m <- seas(foodanddrink,
          xreg=cbind(SatRollOver=SatRollOver,Monday=Monday),
          regression.usertype=cbind('holiday','td'))
```

produces the error.

Going into the log file in the temporary folder created when it runs the package shows the following error message

```
Error messages generated from processing the X-13ARIMA-SEATS spec file 
<snip>\RtmpeAuOR8\x132fd0209371a4/iofile.spc:
Index out of range vector (getstr)
```

At this point, I'm a bit stumped, as the errors aren't very useful, so I was wondering if people had come across it before?

For reference, the spec file generated by seasonal is:

```
series{
  title = "foodanddrink"
  file = "C:\Users\7884961\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpeAuOR8\x132fd02fe41835/data.dta"
  format = "datevalue"
  period = 12
}

transform{
  function = auto
  print = aictransform
}

regression{
  aictest = (td easter)
  usertype = (holiday td)
  user = (xreg1 xreg2)
  file = "C:\Users\7884961\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpeAuOR8\x132fd02fe41835/xreg.dta"
  format = "datevalue"
}

seats{
  noadmiss = yes
  save = (s10 s11 s12 s13 s16 s18)
}

outlier{

}

automdl{
  print = bestfivemdl
}

estimate{
  save = (model estimates residuals)
}

spectrum{
  print = qs
}
```

and the xreg.dta file is:

```
2012 1 0.675 1
2012 2 -0.325 0
2012 3 -0.325 -1
2012 4 0.675 1
2012 5 -0.325 0
2012 6 -0.325 -1
2012 7 0.675 1
2012 8 -0.325 -1
2012 9 -0.325 0
2012 10 0.675 1
2012 11 -0.325 -1
2012 12 -0.325 1
2013 1 -0.325 0
2013 2 -0.325 0
2013 3 -0.325 0
2013 4 0.675 0
2013 5 -0.325 -1
2013 6 -0.325 0
2013 7 0.675 1
2013 8 -0.325 -1
2013 9 0.675 1
2013 10 -0.325 0
2013 11 -0.325 -1
2013 12 0.675 1
2014 1 -0.325 -1
2014 2 -0.325 0
2014 3 -0.325 1
2014 4 -0.325 0
2014 5 -0.325 -1
2014 6 0.675 1
2014 7 -0.325 0
2014 8 -0.325 -1
2014 9 0.675 1
2014 10 -0.325 -1
2014 11 -0.325 0
2014 12 0.675 1
2015 1 -0.325 -1
2015 2 0.675 0
2015 3 0.675 1
2015 4 -0.325 0
2015 5 -0.325 -1
2015 6 0.675 1
2015 7 -0.325 -1
2015 8 -0.325 0
2015 9 0.675 1
2015 10 -0.325 -1
2015 11 0.675 1
2015 12 -0.325 0
2016 1 -0.325 -1
2016 2 0.675 1
2016 3 -0.325 0
2016 4 -0.325 -1
2016 5 0.675 1
2016 6 -0.325 0
2016 7 -0.325 -1
2016 8 0.675 1
2016 9 -0.325 -1
2016 10 -0.325 1
2016 11 -0.325 0
2016 12 -0.325 -1
2017 1 0.675 1
2017 2 -0.325 0
2017 3 -0.325 -1
2017 4 -0.325 0
2017 5 0.675 1
2017 6 -0.325 -1
2017 7 -0.325 1
2017 8 -0.325 0
2017 9 -0.325 -1
2017 10 0.675 1
2017 11 -0.325 0
2017 12 -0.325 -1
2018 1 0.675 1
2018 2 -0.325 0
2018 3 -0.325 0
2018 4 0.675 0
2018 5 -0.325 0
2018 6 -0.325 -1
2018 7 0.675 1
2018 8 -0.325 -1
2018 9 -0.325 0
2018 10 0.675 1
2018 11 -0.325 -1
2018 12 -0.325 1
2019 1 -0.325 0
2019 2 -0.325 0
2019 3 -0.325 -1
2019 4 0.675 1
2019 5 -0.325 -1
2019 6 -0.325 0
2019 7 0.675 1
2019 8 -0.325 -1
2019 9 0.675 1
2019 10 -0.325 0
2019 11 -0.325 -1
2019 12 0.675 1
2020 1 -0.325 -1
2020 2 -0.325 0
2020 3 0.675 1
2020 4 -0.325 0
2020 5 -0.325 -1
2020 6 0.675 1
2020 7 -0.325 -1
2020 8 -0.325 0
2020 9 0.675 1
2020 10 -0.325 -1
2020 11 0.675 1
2020 12 -0.325 0
2021 1 -0.325 -1
2021 2 0.675 0
2021 3 0.675 1
2021 4 -0.325 -1
2021 5 -0.325 0
2021 6 0.675 1
2021 7 -0.325 -1
2021 8 0.675 1
2021 9 -0.325 0
2021 10 -0.325 -1
2021 11 0.675 1
2021 12 -0.325 -1
```